# Alternate poster when video src not found

Tags: javascript, html, video, tags

I have some videos in a table that I'm putting on my site for media outlets to download. I leave the videos in the table regardless if there's a file src. I want to make it super easy for the guys in the field to drop a video in a folder called `video1` with a MP4 named `video1.mp4`. They will also put their file for the poster of the video called `video1.jpg`. This will repeat in folders incrementing along with the files `video2`, `video3`, etc.

I want to put in each folder a `jpg` with a no content logo on it so when there isn't a file in the video target folder, the poster of no content displays. Here's the code for the individual cell in the table:

```
<td>
    <video width="312" height="175" controls>
        <source src="/videos/video1/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not 
            support the video tag.
    </video>
    <a href="/videos/video1/video1.mp4" download="video1">Download this video</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Please specify an actual quetion.

Comment: I want to know what I can add to my above code to to display the no content jpg instead of the default poster if theres not a video in the source folder. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event listener to all the videos that checks if any error occurred. Then if it's an error caused by the video not being loaded correctly (codes 3 or 4, [see the possible error codes here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#error-codes)), add the "no content" logo instead of the video.

Something like this (one video is valid, the other one is not):

```js
var vids = document.querySelectorAll("video");

// for all the videos in the page
for (var x = 0; x < vids.length; x++) {

  // add an event listening for errors
  vids[x].addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    
    // if the error is caused by the video not loading
    if (this.networkState > 2) {
      
      // add an image with the message "video not found"
      this.setAttribute("poster", "http://dummyimage.com/312x175/000/fff.jpg&text=Video+Not+Found");
    }
  }, true);

}
```

```html
<video width="312" height="175" controls>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video width="312" height="175" controls>
  <source src="NON_EXISTING_VIDEO.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You can also see it on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/13ehzz07/).

As a recommendation, instead of having a "no content" image in each folder, it would be better to have only one image in a common place (unless you want to have a personalized "no content" image for each video).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the following code

```
<video controls>
  <source src="something.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    <img src="notfound.jpg" alt="Image Not Found">
</video>

<script>
var v = document.querySelector('video'),
    sources = v.querySelectorAll('source'),
    lastsource = sources[sources.length-1];
lastsource.addEventListener('error', function(ev) {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerHTML = v.innerHTML;
  v.parentNode.replaceChild(d, v);
}, false);
</script>
```

Check out the post here for fallbacks if source not found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Showing_fallback_content_when_no_source_could_be_decoded